# await not waiting to resolve promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

This is my small twilio function/class returning promise which I do import in another file. I am getting **`err`** and **`res`** here returning it in promise

```
class TwilioService {
  sendSms(to, message) {
    return this.twilio.sendMessage(sms,(err,res) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return resolve(res)
        } else {
          console.log(res, 'ppppppppppppppppp')
          return reject(res)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Now this is my function where I am using that function.

But when I do `console.log(sendSms)` I get undefined in the console even I am returning promise from the twilio function. What I am doing wrong here.

```
import Twilio from '../../services/twilio'
const twilio = new Twilio()
const handler = async(request, reply) => {
  try {
    const sendSms = await twilio.sendSms(`+91${mobile}`, `Welcome to App. User ${verificationCode} as your signup OTP.`)
    console.log(sendSms, 'oooooooooooooooo')
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Please help!!! Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning the *callback* at the moment, which probably doesn't return a `Promise` - switch the order around, return the `Promise` that resolves when the `sendMessage` callback runs. Also note that you should `reject` if there an `err` and `resolve` with the `res` if there is no `err`, not the other way around:

```
class TwilioService {
  sendSms(to, message) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {               // switch these two lines
      return this.twilio.sendMessage(sms, (err, res) => {   // switch these two lines
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          return reject(res) // reject on error, don't resolve
        } else {
          console.log(res, 'ppppppppppppppppp')
          return resolve(res) // resolve when there's no error
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This is just awesome. You have answered in a minute. Great understanding man. Last question **will reject throw error in catch part of async function?** I can accept in 5 minutes

Comment: That's right - when a `Promise` rejects, if that `Promise` is `await`ed elsewhere, that `await` line will throw an error (the error that `reject` was called with), and that error can be caught if the `await` line is in a `try` block, so flow will continue in the `catch` block, as your code is doing properly.

Comment: Last question can I make `sendSms` asynchronous and return the value from it instead of using `new Promise` syntax? Because async function itself returns a promise

Comment: Unfortunately no - while an `async` function does return a `Promise` automatically, that `Promise` is not chained to anything but the asynchronous `await`s in the `async` function. The only way to do it would be to `await` the `new Promise((resolve, ...` - but in that case, easier to have `sendSms` be a standard function and just return that constructed `Promise`. (You don't have access to the `resolve` equivalent when you use an `async` function, but you *need* a callable `resolve` when converting a callback to a `Promise`)